# How to validate duplicates with zf2 and doctrine

Tags: forms, validation, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am developing a project in zf2 using doctrine and I want to set up a form validator to determine if an entry is a duplicate.  In mySQL I can set attributes of a field to be a `PRIMARY KEY` to prevent duplicates at that level, but I assume that there needs to be something similar in an input filter for zf2 to provide validation messages.

Comment: Hi, have you already see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754812/uniqueentity-using-doctrine-2) question?

Comment: More specifically, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14790261/1025589.  DoctrineModule provides a validator for just such a purpose.